# Regular Expression for NMAP match lines for Machine & OS only

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, nmap

Using Linux, I'm looking for filter out the data for Machines that are only XP matches and delete consecutive, "nmap scan report for " lines.

```
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.138
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds Microsoft Windows XP microsoft-ds
|   OS: Windows XP (Windows 2000 LAN Manager)
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.139
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.140
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.141
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.143
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds Microsoft Windows XP microsoft-ds
Aggressive OS guesses: Microsoft Windows 2003 Small Business Server SP1 (91%), Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP2 (91%), Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP1 or SP2 (86%), Microsoft Windows XP Professional SP2 (French) (85%)
|   OS: Windows XP (Windows 2000 LAN Manager)
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.144
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.147
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds Microsoft Windows XP microsoft-ds
Aggressive OS guesses: Microsoft Windows 2003 Small Business Server SP1 (91%), Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP2 (90%), Microsoft Windows XP Professional SP2 (French) (85%), Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP1 or SP2 (85%)
|   OS: Windows XP (Windows 2000 LAN Manager)
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.148
OS: Windows XP (Windows 2000 LAN Manager)
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.191
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds Microsoft Windows XP microsoft-ds
Aggressive OS guesses: Microsoft Windows 2003 Small Business Server SP1 (91%), Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP2 (91%), Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP1 or SP2 (86%), Microsoft Windows XP Professional SP2 (French) (85%)
|   OS: Windows XP (Windows 2000 LAN Manager)
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.192
OS details: Microsoft Windows 2000 SP2 - SP4, Windows XP SP2 - SP3, or Windows Server 2003 SP0 - SP2
```

Looking for a report that only shows:

```
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.138
OS: Windows XP (Windows 2000 LAN Manager)
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.147
OS: Windows XP (Windows 2000 LAN Manager)
```

My idea was to use awk,grep, sed, or perl: m/^Nmap.*\n.*!(^Nmap).*/m
Looking for the lines beginning with Nmap, and after the newline copy the next lines that are not beginning with Nmap, such as "OS: Windows XP". Then start again ...

Thank you for the help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F "OS: " '/^Nmap/ {a=$0} /OS:/ {print a"\n"FS$2}' file
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.138
OS: Windows XP (Windows 2000 LAN Manager)
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.143
OS: Windows XP (Windows 2000 LAN Manager)
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.147
OS: Windows XP (Windows 2000 LAN Manager)
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.148
OS: Windows XP (Windows 2000 LAN Manager)
Nmap scan report for 13.93.27.191
OS: Windows XP (Windows 2000 LAN Manager)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. Simple, one-liner, kungfu.

Answer (score 1):

When the problem is searching Nmap output, the answer is **always**, "Use the [XML output format](http://nmap.org/book/output-formats-xml-output.html)." This is because Nmap's regular output can change between versions and is not structured for machine input. zyou can get Nmap to emit XML with the `-oX` or `-oA` options.

You've already filtered the output down a lot, but I can tell from the "|" at the beginning of the lines that the output you want comes from a [NSE script](http://nmap.org/book/nse.html) instead of the OS detection engine. Specifically, that is the output of the [`smb-os-discovery`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-os-discovery) script. Knowing this, we can use an XML parser to look for each element `//script[@id='smb-os-discovery']` whose `output` attribute contains the string "OS: Windows XP". Here's how to do that with [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//script[@id='smb-os-discovery' and contains(@output, 'OS: Windows XP')" -v "ancestor::host/address[@addrtype='ipv4']/@addr" -n scan-output.xml
```

You can do similar things with the many XML parsing libraries in every language. Python, Perl, and Ruby all have good parsers specifically designed for Nmap's XML output.

EDIT: Since you only want the OS as detected by `smb-os-detection`, you could save time scanning by only running this script and skipping the OS fingerprinting step. Here's an example of a fast scan like this:

```
nmap -p 445 --script smb-os-detection -oA smb-scan-%y%m%d 192.0.2.0/24
```

Comment: Thanks, awesome XML kungfu, and sharing advice on XML output. It makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
 perl -ne 'if (/nmap/i) { $nmap = $_ }; if (/(OS:.*XP.*)/) { print $nmap,$1,"\n"; }' report
```

Comment: Thanks, I will most likely in the future create a perl script for a monthly cron job.

Comment: @Jotne, I believe the question was posed specifically for Windows XP.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this would be for a future perl project. I accepted the AWK answer because I needed something simpler for now. I meant to say, in the following priority: awk, grep, sed, or lastly perl.